# Marketo API - Maximum of 10 concurrent API calls

Tags: api, concurrency, marketo

I'd like to know what Marketo means by 10 concurrent API calls. If for example 20 people use an API in the same time, is it going to crash ? And if I make the script sleep for X seconds if I get that limit response and try the API call again, will it work ?
Thanks,
Best Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Maximum of 10 concurrent API calls means, that Marketo will process only 10 simultaneous API requests per subscription at maximum.

So, for example if you have a service that directly queries the API every time it is used, and this very service gets called 11 or more times in the same time, than Marketo will respond with an error message for the eleventh call and the rest. The first 10 calls should be processed fine. According to the [docs](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/error-codes/#response_level_error_codes), the error message the following requests will receive will have an error code of `615`.

If your script is single threaded (like standard PHP) and you have more that 10 API calls, and your script is running in one instance, than you are fine, since the calls are performed one after another (so they are not concurrent). However, if your script can run in multiple instance you can hit the limit easily. In case a sleep won't help you, but you can always check the response code in your script and retry the call if it received an error. This retry process is often called *Exponential Backoff*. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) is a great article on this topic.